# The sql codes shown in the document is not running on azure synapse dedicate sql pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have the following [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/DP-203T00-Data-Engineering-on-Microsoft-Azure/blob/main/Instructions/Labs/02/README.md)

when I copy paste the following syntax

```
-- Create DimProductCategory PK
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimProductCategory] WITH CHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DimProductCategory_ProductCategoryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductCategoryKey]
    )  ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

The syntax `WITH CHECK ADD` is not working. Also, many syntax from the document is not working wondering why it is not working on sql pool. is there an alternative way or any other documents related to this from azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax will not work on Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools and you will receive the following error(s):

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Parse error at line: 2, column:
> 40: Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'.
>
> Msg 104467, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Enforced unique constraints are
> not supported. To create an unenforced unique constraint you must
> include the NOT ENFORCED syntax as part of your statement.

The way to write this syntax would be using `ALTER TABLE` to add a non-clustered and non-enforced primary key, eg

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimProductCategory] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_DimProductCategory_ProductCategoryKey] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( [ProductCategoryKey] ) NOT ENFORCED;
```

However as this table is a dimension, I would also suggest changing its distribution to `REPLICATE`, which you have to do in the table definition.  So the whole statement would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimProductCategory](
    [ProductCategoryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE NOT ENFORCED,
    [ProductCategoryAlternateKey] [int] NULL,
    [EnglishProductCategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SpanishProductCategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FrenchProductCategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE,
    CLUSTERED INDEX( [ProductCategoryKey] )
)
```

It will be a good exercise for you to convert the rest of the syntax in the lab.  The foreign keys won't work either.

Comment: Hi @wBob  thankyou for your reply I could create table successfully and alter it using the above tips As you mentioned in the post foreign key is throwing error. Please provide some tips to use alter for foreign keys

Comment: Hi @RRD, foreign keys are not supported at all in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools.  Simply do not run those statements.  Please consider upvoting and/or marking the above as the answer if it's been helpful to you.